# Can I import an android studio project to eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, migration, android-studio

I would like to know if it is possible to import an android studio project to eclipse.

So far I tried:

- Import directly from eclipse: imported a bunch of weird projects without any code
- It seems like InteliJ has an export to eclipse feature, but I don't see any reference to it in android studio...

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was down voted. The problem lies in having multiple modules each with their own resources and manifest files. I had to manually paste each of my classes and files into their appropriate packages, combine all the manifest files into one and paste each of the resources into the res folder to get it to work. PS. don't forget to import the external libraries. +1 to this question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you open an Android Studio project in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745793/how-do-you-open-an-android-studio-project-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

the best solution so far is to copy each XML and JAVA ... into the new project manually .

it is hard but it works

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import the project directly but it's not to hard to achieve it:

- Create a new Android empty project in eclipse
- Overwrite the fresh `res/` folder and the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, with the ones from the Android Studio project
- Copy the content of the `java/` folder from the Android Studio project (it should contain your package name folder structure, like `com/example/app/`, and the java files of course) in the Eclipse `src` folder
- Link your needed libraries if it's the case

Basically the Android application fundamental elements are the java files, the manifest file and the resources. From there you can build back a project in your favorite IDE

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can. In eclipse, select file > import > Android > Existing code into workspace and click import.

That's it.

Comment: Really wish it was that simple! When I try to do something like that it detects 5 or more projects when I select my android studio project, and none of them gets any of the code...

Comment: actually I didn't use Android Studio but I thought it should work on InteliJ because it works with netbeans.

Comment: This imports the project with empty src directory. Does not work!