# How to port a Gradle based Android Studio project to Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to port CouchbaseLite project from Android Studio to Eclipse which uses Maven.

How can I achieve this?

If needed, project's link is here.
http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/cbl-android/#getting-started

Comment: You mean Gradle based Android Project to Eclipse without Maven and Gradle? :)

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to run this Android Studio based project on Eclipse.

Comment: Then title of your question is wrong, Android Studio uses Gradle, not Maven

Comment: It uses Gradle files in which Maven repositories are specified.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722773/import-existing-gradle-git-project-into-eclipse-for-example-hibernate-orm

Comment: Hey thanks for this link. It might help me. Is it sure that any Android Studio project will become compatible to Eclispse using this strategy.

Comment: Best Working Solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130157/can-i-import-an-android-studio-project-to-eclipse/29214033#29214033

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio uses Gradle, not Maven, but artifacts are downloaded from Maven Repositories. Your question is not related to Maven.

Gradle has support for eclipse, simply add eclipse plugin

```
apply plugin: "eclipse"
```

and invoke

```
gradle eclipse
```

More options are described here: [Import existing Gradle Git project into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722773/import-existing-gradle-git-project-into-eclipse-for-example-hibernate-orm)

Other option is to use [Gradle Integration for Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse)

Comment: It is a thumbs up from my side. But let me take my time 2-5 days when I will try it and I will accept your answer.