# Migrate android studio project to eclipse

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to use a project built in  Android Studio in Eclipse How  am I able to import an  Android Studio project into  Eclipse? If it possible please state the steps to follow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481915/how-to-import-android-studio-project-in-eclipse

Comment: Best Working Solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130157/can-i-import-an-android-studio-project-to-eclipse/29214033#29214033

Answer (score 2):

Import the project in Eclipse and copy the packages inside java package into src package and look for errors, if any, and fix them. I have tried it.