# Importing a Gradle project into Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

I'm trying to import a gradle project into eclipse but I'm getting this error :

"The SDK directory '\Applications\Android Studio.app\sdk' does not exist."

Has anyone encountered this kind of problem?

Comment: `'\Applications\Android Studio.app\sdk' ` in Eclipse? Probably an environment variable is messed up, ANDROID_HOME.

Comment: I know... that is really strange for me too!

Comment: Check your Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> ANDROID_HOME and see where it points, if it doesn't point anywhere then specify the directory to the SDK

Comment: I don't have an ANDROID_HOME variable...instead I have a JAVA_HOME variable that points to > C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481915/how-to-import-android-studio-project-in-eclipse/26092617#26092617

Answer (score 0):

Clean project manually (delete all IDE) and check Eclipse SDK settings.

Answer (score -1):

From the command line execute

> gradle eclipse

Now you can import the gradle project as a normal eclipse project.

for more info - http://codetutr.com/2013/03/23/how-to-import-gradle-project-into-eclipse/