# android studio and eclipse interop

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, ide

All of our Android projects are developed with Eclipse, and we're not yet ready for the move to Android Studio.

Some developers want to start using Studio on one of the projects (A). This project depends on other projects, B and C.

Can team members work with those different IDEs on project A without interfering each other?

Comment: I don't think so. There are differences in the project structures, files and so on. Eclipse ADT is now deprecated and there isn't an active support anymore, you are walking on the fire :)

Comment: AS and Eclipse have different folders and files. You can migrate projects from Eclipse to AS. Therefore is a little hard to reverse that. look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481915/how-to-import-android-studio-project-in-eclipse

Comment: @greywolf82 Your comment that the ADT plugin has no active development is incorrect. There were two releases in 2015: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html