# Using android studio project In eclipse project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

I have an application built with eclipse and now I want to use this library https://github.com/worker8/TourGuide in my project.

I've been trying to do a "manual import" as suggested by @Julian in this thread [How to import Android Studio project in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481915/how-to-import-android-studio-project-in-eclipse) , but I've made no progress with it.

Can anyone please share any information on how to use a library such as TourGuide in an eclipse project? is it even possible?

thanks

Comment: It may not be possible, though usually it is. You will need to make your own Eclipse-style project tree that moves the libraries Java code, resources, the manifest, and so on in their Eclipse-style spots. You should then be able to import that project tree into Eclipse. All that being said, Eclipse support has ended, and so you need to consider moving to a supported Android IDE (e.g., Android Studio, IntelliJ IDEA, or perhaps later this year the Eclipse-based AndDown).

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, I guess I'll have to keep trying