# Error Occurs while Running Android Project - Unsupported major.minor version

Tags: java, android, eclipse

While running the code it shows a alert

> *Errors occurred during the build 
>   Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' 
>   on project 'Test'.com/android/dx/command/dexer/Main : 
>   Unsupported major.minor version 52.0*

[image: This is the error shown]

Eclipse was running properly but after the updation of eclipse it shows the error.previously it was running well,i.e before updation
help me solve this issue and run my project.

also help me with some update-able adt bundle.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0

Comment: Google  https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Unsupported+major.minor+version+52.0&oq=Unsupported+major.minor+version+52.0&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.887j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Please check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481915/how-to-import-android-studio-project-in-eclipse

Comment: try to delete bin folder from eclipse you dex might get conflict

Comment: In addition to others, Updating your Java may also solve your problem. It seems ....dexer.Main.class file compiled by newer Java Compiler.

Comment: that doesnot work @PräTîkTank

Comment: I need to know how to solve this issue and how to run this in eclipse @KNeerajLal

Comment: @VishnuAnil What component did you update in eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the issue , Previously I compiled with jAVA 1.7 and run in jdk 1.8 that was the reason of my issue now i download JAVA 1.8 now it is running

- J2SE 8=52,
- J2SE 7=51,
- J2SE 6.0=50,
- J2SE 5.0=49,
- JDK 1.4=48,
- JDK 1.3=47,
- JDK 1.2=46
- JDK 1.1=45

[image]

Answer (score 50):

I have got the same exact issue, but not the same solution solved it :

To fix this, i have to go in my `project.properties` file :

[image]

And in this file add this line :

```
sdk.buildtools=23.0.3
```

Comment: Thank you! I have the same issue, this solve my problem!

Answer (score 4):

your code might has been compiled with Java Higher version(i.e. 8), while you are trying to run it with Java Lower version(i.e. 7). Note that Eclipse has it's own compiler and does not use the one from the JDK and most probably it is configured to use Java Higher version(i.e. 8). Check you eclipse compiler preferences.

Answer (score 3):

The only one reason for **Unsupported major.minor version 52.0** in eclipse is API Level 24

So please do following things to resolve Issue in Eclipse :

1. GO To **Window** menu
   2.Open **Android SDK manager**
   3.Check is API level 24 is installed any Platform
   4.If **YES** Please Uninstall this API level 24 Packages.
   5.Clean Project and Run Again.

And its Work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below line in project.properties and setting Java to 1.7 solved the issue to me.

**sdk.buildtools=23.0.3**