# Android SDK project import to Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Because my office don't allow install Android SDK, in my PC only have Eclipse.
So, are there any way to import Android Project from Git to Eclipse without Android SDK ?
I just want to compile code, not need simulation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17491579/7518802 may be this answer help you

Comment: ok thanks Kamesh Talreja