# Why I am unable to build the Android source?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-build, googleio

Google has released [Google IO 13 Android App source code](https://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/checkout).

After git clone and importing project, I got lot of issues while building, which you can [find here](https://code.google.com/p/iosched/issues/detail?id=42). After passing all the issues, it now says:

> **Could not find HomeActivity.apk!**

Here is a screenshot of my build process:

[image: Build screenshot]

How can I build the source code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iosched 2013 application was developed with Android Studio IDE and not with Eclipse,
the whole file structure is different, this is why eclipse can't find some of the project's files.

You can download the Android Studio from here: [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html)

Comment: is there any way to port that code to eclipse . dont want to go to studio till a stable version arrives

Comment: As far as I know no, there is no way to port it since eclipse + the eclipse's android plugin do not support the new build system.

About Android Studio stability, I've been working with it for more then a month and currently now it's much more stable the eclipse, even in it's "Preview" version.

Comment: yes there is no way . Android SDK tech lead XAV also mentions that http://stackoverflow.com/a/16747412/1506239

Answer (score 6):

In case somebody still couldn't find IOSched 2013 for Eclipse.
I have the ported version in here :

https://github.com/yodiaditya/iosched-2013-eclipse

Answer (score 4):

On my GitHub mirror, I have an [**eclipse** branch](https://github.com/jjdstr/iosched/commits/eclipse) that have the changes I mentioned in the Google Code issues page to make it work. It launch and seems to runs fine on my phone (although I didn't test much further than that).

You will need to adjust the reference to both `/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat` and `/google-play-services_lib` library projects to [match your setup](https://github.com/jjdstr/iosched/blob/f8d92a79c43fb515cdd29a79b8624fd306ebb79a/android/src/main/project.properties) before it can compile on your machine.

UPDATE 1: [This commit](https://github.com/jjdstr/iosched/commit/e9c387cb3efcdcb0c58216bd00bec7b8a97f4475) added the appcompat and google-play-services_lib projects into the repo for easier access.

UPDATE 2: Now [updated with latest version](https://github.com/jjdstr/iosched/commit/55a53045f3728fe7619ff8b80ec6803f0e791053) (iosched 2014).