# Json parser http get error?

Tags: java, android, json

Hi I have problem with my application. I use android studio. My EditProductActivity.java class looks like:

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EditProductActivity extends Activity {

    EditText txtName;
    EditText txtPrice;
    EditText txtDesc;
    EditText txtCreatedAt;
    Button btnSave;
    Button btnDelete;

    String pid;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // single product url
    private static final String url_product_detials = "http://fastfix.net.pl/777/get_product_details.php";

    // url to update product
    private static final String url_update_product = "http://fastfix.net.pl/777/update_product.php";

    // url to delete product
    private static final String url_delete_product = "http://fastfix.net.pl/777/delete_product.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_product);

        // save button
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

        // getting product details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // getting product id (pid) from intent
        pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

        // Getting complete product details in background thread
        new GetProductDetails().execute();

        // save button click event
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // starting background task to update product
                new SaveProductDetails().execute();
            }
        });

        // Delete button click event
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // deleting product in background thread
                new DeleteProduct().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
     * */
    class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            // product with this pid found
                            // Edit Text
                            txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                            txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                            txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                            // display product data in EditText
                            txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                            txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                            txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                        }else{
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to  Save product Details
     * */
    class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Saving product ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Saving product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // getting updated data from EditTexts
            String name = txtName.getText().toString();
            String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
            String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PRICE, price));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description));

            // sending modified data through http request
            // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check json success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully updated
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    // send result code 100 to notify about product update
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to update product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product uupdated
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /*****************************************************************
     * Background Async Task to Delete Product
     * */
    class DeleteProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Product...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Deleting product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_delete_product, "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Delete Product", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // product successfully deleted
                    // notify previous activity by sending code 100
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    // send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }
}
```

And error log show's:

```
03-17 14:20:17.782  11003-11003/com.example.androidhive E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java)
            at com.example.androidhive.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:62)
            at com.example.androidhive.EditProductActivity$GetProductDetails$1.run(EditProductActivity.java:131)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-17 14:20:17.797      520-551/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ App crashed! Process: com.example.androidhive
03-17 14:20:17.797      520-551/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ App crashed! Package: com.example.androidhive v1 (1.0)
03-17 14:20:17.797      520-551/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ Application Label: My Application
```

Please help me what I must add to code. I know where is error but i don't have to know how to resolve that problem.

Comment: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException you could have googled and found many questions already for this

Comment: @Blimer I answered below, you can see my answer, keep me alive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should get json data on anathor thread like this:
you can open another class like this:

```
public class web_api_get  extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, String> {

     @Override
    public String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        HttpParams params2 = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params2, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params2, "UTF-8");
        params2.setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.expect-continue", false);


        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params2); 
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]+""); 
        try {       
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
          StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine(); 
          int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
          if (statusCode == 200) {  
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              builder.append(line);
            }
          } else {
           // Log.e(ParseJSON.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
          } 

            } catch (Exception e) { 
            }

        return builder.toString(); 
    } 

}
```

and then you can call like this on mainactivity;

```
String return_json=new web_api_get().execute("your_url").get() ;
```

keep me what is going on

Comment: I do not know if I understand you. I should create new class and paste this?

Comment: yep you can create new class name web_api_get and past the code in that, and then you can call it from mainactivity

Comment: @Blimer could you see the answer? is it useful for you?

Comment: I create new class. But I don't know why it's not working.
http://i.imgur.com/yYQp2XW.png

Comment: @Blimer if it is not problem can you ut your project github and give me link , and then I see the real issue and maybe I can find a solution you problem

Comment: catch:
https://github.com/blimer/first_app/commit/b44ffc6b80ea8c1b41caf3b96495323c7226d072

Comment: No. I still wait for your help.

Comment: please update your project on github because when I download it I cant open it in my eclipse

Comment: Maby beacause I use android studio?

Comment: most probably can you convert to eclipse studio? I think this solution is working, if you put project which can import eclipse I can show how you can do it

Comment: Imposible :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745793/how-do-you-open-an-android-studio-project-in-eclipse

Can you install android studio? OR this is toturial who I use:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: I make this project in eclipse and work! :D Thanks for interesting :D

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0jvrkl1qim6f5td/eclipse.rar
Here is this project

Comment: ok I am happy to see it is working , I think my answer maybe is upvoted by you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to establish your connections in an async thread. Main Thread is commonly for handling your UI tasks, not your background tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Android would be really happy If you write following block of code in onCreate or in onPreExcecute but not in doInBackground. ( doInBackground gets called in non-ui thread.)

```
                            // product with this pid found
                            // Edit Text
                            txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                            txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                            txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                            // display product data in EditText
                            txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                            txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                            txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));
```

Comment: I changed to "onCreate" but still not working