# Is it possible to have a Android Studio formatted project to work on Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have succeed to run my android project from Eclipse to Android Studio simply by generating its gradle build (without changing the project's structure).

I would like to change this project structure to the Android Studio's format, however im afraid this p**roject will not be working anymore in Eclipse**.

Have someone did this before?Did the re-structured project still working in Eclipse? (I have a bad feeling about this)

**Note** : If you wondering why i dont try it before asking, its because the project is fairly complicated (around 5 libraries also need to be restructured and i only know a very little about gradle) so it will be nice if i know it will be working.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I found answer here...Please take look at that.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/21159299/2931489

Comment: @BabulPatel if im not mistaken, that answer will lead me to have 2 different project, each one for each IDE. My goal is (if possible) to have only one project for both IDE. Thanks for your help