# Errors while opening sample android studio project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk, apk

I am trying to open android studio project in eclipse. I am very much new to android application development.

I followed the below steps [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21159299/13317) suggested by someone to open android studio project in eclipse.

> You cannot import the project directly but it's not to hard to achieve it:
>
> 1. Create a new Android empty project in eclipse
>
> 2. Overwrite the fresh res/ folder and the AndroidManifest.xml file, with the ones from the Android Studio project
>
> 3. Copy the content of the java/ folder from the Android Studio project (it should contain your package name folder structure, like com/example/app/, and the java files of course) in the Eclipse src folder
>
> 4.Link your needed libraries if it's the case
> Basically the Android application fundamental elements are the java files, the manifest file and the resources. From there you can build back a project in your favorite IDE.

But still I am getting the following errors:

1. Installation failed due to invalid APK file.
2. lib/ reserved for NDK libraries.
3. The following libraries were found:

   - lib/armeabi-v7a/libvrtoolkit.so
     The library 'cardboard.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
     Additionally some of those libraries will interfer with the installation of the application.`

Help me fixing them.