# How to migrate Android Studio project to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, adt

I've created a little app in Android Studio based on Google Maps, but now I want to upgrade it and I want to work in Eclipse (I find it easier). The problem is, when I try to open an existing project in Eclipse (that project), it doesn't find the .java files or the .xml at that address, but it works perfectly fine in Android Studio.

Do I have to rewrite all the code in order for it to work in Eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse (I'm assuming you're using ADT) and Android Studio expect the code to be in totally different places.  So while you don't need to rewrite the code, you do need to reorganize the project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you open an Android Studio project in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745793/how-do-you-open-an-android-studio-project-in-eclipse)

Comment: Note that Google is no longer supporting Eclipse. In particular, the Play Services SDK is no longer being distributed in a library project that can be used with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a new project in Eclipse

2.Copy and paste .java, .xml and manifest files in the new eclipse project.

3.Manually import external libraries (if any).

4.Important to maintain project structure use refactor for this purpose, if 
needed.

**P.S If you are looking for developing android apps in future, it is recommended to use Android Studio.**