# Can we use "Android-Studio" package as library project for Android Project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, adt

I need to reuse package of android studio in that android project which is eclipse based. (ADT enabled). Is there any way?

Comment: import `Eclipse` project to `Android Studio`. Then `File -> New -> Import Module...` to import the package already created

Comment: inversely , i want to import android-studio project in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Import `Eclipse` project to Android Studio. Then `File -> New -> Import Module`... to import the package already created.

If you would to do in inverse mode, please read: [How do you open an Android Studio project in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745793/how-do-you-open-an-android-studio-project-in-eclipse)

Already the best solution is to open your `eclipse` project, create the new module for your app and rewrite the created in Android Studio.

Read also: https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html to be aware of that:

> The Eclipse ADT plugin is no longer supported per our announcement.
>   Android Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should
>   migrate your projects to Android Studio as soon as possible. For more
>   information on transitioning to Android Studio, see Migrate to Android
>   Studio from Eclipse.

Hope it will help

Comment: I was working on project using API 19 in Eclipse. I tried to migrate to android-studio (newest). But i faced so many problems like (bla bla .. cannot be resolved)