# Trying to import library to android project with maven and/or gradle

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, groovy, gradle

I'm pretty new to android and I am trying to import a library into my project (I'm using eclipse), specifically https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View. In the read me it gives instructions on how to import it to your project saying to "grab via maven":

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.alamkanak</groupId>
      <artifactId>android-week-view</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.7</version>
      <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

and **grab via gradle**:

```
compile 'com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.1.7'
```

I haven't had experience or any previous knowledge of these two terms, tried to google it and couldn't find how to do that or what it means. If anyone could provide some info or help on how to do that that would be great, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Via gradle, you open your gradle file inside you **app folder** and you will see the **dependencies** inside that you can add:
`compile 'com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.1.7'`

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.1.7
}
```

and then sync your gradle with your app, android studio will prompt you to update the gradle file, after that, you can use the library.

Comment: I'm using eclipse and the adt, is there anyway to use it with eclipse or should I switch to the android studio

Comment: In my opinion, you should switch to android studio, this is my opinion. https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html this will help you.

Comment: If you want to stay with eclipse here is a thread for you to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20448596/android-studio-vs-eclipse-adt-plugin

Answer (score 0):

please use this dependency
 implementation 'com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.1.0
not need any other maven dependecy