# Import all settings from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, adt

Google has announced that ADT plugin for Eclipse is no longer in active development.

> [If you're a new Android developer, you should consider starting with Android Studio, ***because the ADT plugin for Eclipse is no longer in active development.***](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download)

I have my own formatter which I have slightly modified from [original version](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/ide/eclipse/android-formatting.xml) of android formatter, I couldn't find a way to import it.

**Clean Up - Customized Clean up.**

**Customized look.**
**Left** : Eclipse, **Right** : [Studio with eclipse theme](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3421045/1008278). Still not close enough.

[image: Eclipse vs Android Studio]

- How to import all settings under `Preferences > Java > Code Style > *4` from Eclipse to Android Studio.?
- **Map all shortcuts & it's functionalities**.

Comment: Perhaps you could rephrase this question into its more specific, objective parts (e.g. map shortcuts, import code style preferences)? Presenting this as a "should I switch" question is likely to get it closed as "opinion based".

Comment: @matiash please feel free to edit the question, add or remove any to make it better.

Comment: Yes. The question is WHEN to switch. If you're on the fence about switching just wait until Android Studio is out of Beta (and has the kinks worked out.)

Comment: If I were you, I would learn the new keybindings and shortcuts. This will make it much easier for you to work in a team using AS, and mentor new developers.

Comment: Oh, interesting, has this notification for Eclipse ADT plugin getting deprecated been on the download site for a long while already?

Comment: @VenomVendor did you get any theme for the studio closer to eclipse?

Comment: @SmitPatel Yes, I managed to create my own.

Comment: @VenomVendor can you share the xml or theme file so other can use as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get the Eclipse Look & Feel by modifying `Colors & Fonts.`
[Copy of settings.jar](http://www.mediafire.com/download/rqaee885rz5cg5r/settings.jar)

**Usage :**

```
Android Studio
    |-- File
         |--> Import Settings --> Select settings.jar --> Select All --> Import
         |--> Default Settings/Preferences
                |--> KeyMap -->  Mac OS X 10.5+ copy {if mac} / Eclipse.
                |--> Editor
                       |--> Colors & Fonts --> Eclipse
```

Comment: good try but i'm using the windows eclipse Mars so not got the closer theme in studio like eclipse mars.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you switch over to Android Studio. Here I mention why:

1. Google will enforce the Android Studio / Gradle project structure. Sample Code will be released in this format.
2. 3rd party libraries will not be released in a format that's easy to include in Eclipse anymore. They will use gradle. Gradle & Eclipse? Google it, people don't seem to be happy.
3. As Android Studio gets better and the ADT plugin for Eclipse is discontinued, you will glance over to AS and it's new shiny features and be jealous.
4. Everything you said about shortcuts & code formatting are just excuses. I switched from Eclipse to AS 8 weeks ago and forgot 95% of the Eclipse shortcuts (and learned 95% of the Eclipse shortcuts I knew on AS). Print out a cheatsheet, put it on your desk and roll.
   If you don't fancy the default settings of AS / IntelliJ, please name one setting or shortcut that can't be customized.
5. Gradle really has a lot to offer. Look at the 'product flavors' feature, it's great! If you've built 5 variants of one app with a mouseclick you don't want to go back!

Answer (score 4):

#### You can use the default settings from Eclipse by

1. Go to  `File > Settings > Keymap`
2. Then in Keymaps dropdown choose Eclipse.

Now, you may use the default settings from Eclipse. You can also change the other settings if you like.