# Eclipse error plugin

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

know anyone how I can solve that problem from eclipse? I don't know how but it give me that error?

---

### STATUS

```
pluginId            org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor
pluginVersion       3.9.100.v20141023-1946
code                0
severity            4
message             Editor could not be initialized.
fingerprint         92309e7e

Exception:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/ui/views/contentoutline/IContentOutlinePage
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.getAdapter(JavaEditor.java:2205)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.getAdapter(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1776)
 at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:1484)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.internalDoSetInput(JavaEditor.java:2590)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.doSetInput(JavaEditor.java:2563)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.doSetInput(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1392)
 at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$19.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3220)
 at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:463)
 at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:371)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$14.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2156)
 at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2152)
 at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3238)
 at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3265)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:361)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:319)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:898)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:879)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:121)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:345)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:264)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:104)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:55)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:971)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:640)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:695)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:99)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:186)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:145)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4633)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:211)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:85)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
 at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:494)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:458)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:724)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:396)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1166)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3234)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3149)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3131)
 at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3126)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3090)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3080)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:373)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:179)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:268)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:233)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:275)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:251)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:376)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:538)
 at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
 at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:854)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
 at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
 at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:851)
 at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1168)
 at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1275)
 at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:278)
 at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:272)
 at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:313)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4481)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1327)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3819)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3430)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
 at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

---

### REPORT

```
anonymousId         173064ff-7ae0-46b1-8f6a-a20cdffa13c4
name                
email               
comment             The problematic package         'org.eclipse.ui.views.contentoutline' may originate in the following bundles:
org.eclipse.ui.views 3.8.0.v20150422-0725, from which the following bundles present on the stack trace import it: org.eclipse.ui.ide 3.11.0.v20150510-1749 org.eclipse.jdt.ui 3.11.0.v20150527-0925

eclipseBuildId      4.5.0.I20150603-2000
eclipseProduct      org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
javaRuntimeVersion  1.8.0_51-b16
osgiWs              gtk
osgiOs              Linux
osgiOsVersion       3.19.0
osgiArch            x86_64
logMessage          false
ignoreSimilar       false
```

---

### BUNDLES

```
name                org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable
version             1.5.0.v20150422-0725

name                org.eclipse.core.databinding
version             1.5.0.v20150422-0725

name                org.eclipse.core.runtime
version             3.11.0.v20150405-1723

name                org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts
version             1.4.0.v20150421-2214

name                org.eclipse.e4.core.di
version             1.5.0.v20150421-2214

name                org.eclipse.e4.ui.services
version             1.2.0.v20150422-0725

name                org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench
version             1.3.0.v20150531-1948

name                org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt
version             0.13.0.v20150603-0857

name                org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt
version             0.13.0.v20150504-0621

name                org.eclipse.emf.common
version             2.11.0.v20150512-0501

name                org.eclipse.equinox.app
version             1.3.300.v20150423-1356

name                org.eclipse.equinox.event
version             1.3.100.v20140115-1647

name                org.eclipse.equinox.launcher
version             1.3.100.v20150511-1540

name                org.eclipse.jdt.ui
version             3.11.0.v20150527-0925

name                org.eclipse.jdt
version             3.11.0.v20150603-2000

name                org.eclipse.jface
version             3.11.0.v20150602-1400

name                org.eclipse.osgi
version             3.10.100.v20150529-1857

name                org.eclipse.swt
version             3.104.0.v20150528-0211

name                org.eclipse.ui
version             3.107.0.v20150507-1945

name                org.eclipse.ui.ide.application
version             1.1.0.v20150422-0725

name                org.eclipse.ui.ide
version             3.11.0.v20150510-1749
```

If I've try to open one class(any class) it will not open, any class will be open something like that:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFU4m.png

Is not about android, it's about every thing....

Comment: Close your projects. Close eclipse. Reopen. **Sometimes is the fix

Comment: I've do it x2-3 times... but nothing happen

Comment: So if you have done it 1 time. If i substitute into that equation you have tried -1 times??

Comment: I've try reset my eclipse x2-x3 times, after that I've try to move my project in another folder and again nothing happened. And the last think what I've tried is to clear all project and rebuild, but again, nothing happened

Comment: I don't see org.eclipse.ui.views in your Bundles list. Is that list incomplete, or are you missing that bundle somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You're using an IDE/project format/build system that is no longer supported by Google/Android. You simply can not expect things to work within a deprecated system.

Move your project to Android Studio and Gradle, see what happens, ask questions about it but don't expect things to work with a system that's gone and done with.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom I'm not saying you can't . I'm saying that for several months (years even? this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617638/will-eclipse-adt-be-dates dates back to May 2013) Google (as the main and sole Android maintainer) has decided to discontinue Eclipse as an Android IDE. You can still use it but you can't expect things to work. 
Your question, without looking at it in detail may still be a valid question as to 'why stuff doesn't work' in the same sense as 'why does my floppy disk not load on a Commodore C64' might be a valid question. Just pointing out that

Comment: you're not using the up-to-date-tools to produce an Android app and you can't and shouldn't expect things to work or people to be able to heklp you.