# The rendering target (Android 4.0) is still loading. The layout will refresh automatically once the process is finished

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Recently I updated my Android SDK Tools to the latest version v24.3.4 and had ADT v23.0.7.2120684 installed. Then when i open my eclipse Graphic Layout editor,it cannot represent any view and prompt "**The rendering target (Android 4.0) is still loading. The layout will refresh automatically once the process is finished.**"
besides,the eclipse show a error log dialoge said:

```
**Error loggged in org.eclise.ui
Message:Unhandled event loop exception**  
……
```

i click the detials and see the following log :

```
------
STATUS
------
pluginId            org.eclipse.ui
pluginVersion       3.107.0.v20150507-1945
code                0
severity            4
message             Unhandled event loop exception
fingerprint         87c316ce

Exception:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/ide/common        /rendering/api/LayoutlibCallback
 at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
 at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
 at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
 at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
 at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
 at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.LayoutlibCallback cannot be found by com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_23.0.7.2120684
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
 at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
 at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
 at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
 at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
 at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)

------
REPORT
------
anonymousId         a62d15c3-3b7a-453e-bb1c-bfd3a4581ac0
name                
email               
comment             The problematic package         'com.android.ide.common.rendering.api' may originate in the following bundles:
  com.android.ide.eclipse.base 23.0.6.1720515, from which the following     bundles present on the stack trace import it:
    com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 23.0.7.2120684

eclipseBuildId      4.5.0.I20150603-2000
eclipseProduct      org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
javaRuntimeVersion  1.8.0_45-b15
osgiWs              win32
osgiOs              Windows7
osgiOsVersion       6.1.0
osgiArch            x86_64
logMessage          false
ignoreSimilar       false

-------
BUNDLES
-------
name                com.android.ide.eclipse.adt
version             23.0.7.2120684

name                org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable
version             1.5.0.v20150422-0725

name                org.eclipse.core.databinding
version             1.5.0.v20150422-0725

name                org.eclipse.core.runtime
version             3.11.0.v20150405-1723

name                org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench
version             1.3.0.v20150531-1948

name                org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt
version             0.13.0.v20150504-0621

name                org.eclipse.equinox.app
version             1.3.300.v20150423-1356

name                org.eclipse.equinox.launcher
version             1.3.100.v20150511-1540

name                org.eclipse.osgi
version             3.10.100.v20150529-1857

name                org.eclipse.swt
version             3.104.0.v20150528-0211

name                org.eclipse.ui
version             3.107.0.v20150507-1945

name                org.eclipse.ui.ide.application
version             1.1.0.v20150422-0725

name                org.eclipse.ui.ide
version             3.11.0.v20150510-1749
```

I know that the Android SDK and ADT are supposed to be the same version ,but ADT v23.0.7.2120684 has been the latest version.

now what should i do?

Comment: Switch to Android Studio, since ADT is deprecated now: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617638/will-eclipse-adt-be-deprecated

Comment: Just use lower version API on **xml Graphic layout** if its not rendering the view. You can have project target build with 23 and on any xml Grahipcal layout you can change to lower api to render the view.